# Change the onclick of a hyper link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update the click event of the hyperlink onClick and want to update the html inside the hyperlink in jquery

**HTML**

```
<a class=" save" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="save_unsave('unsave','UID','ID',this);">
    <div class="jopt_iconwrap" title="Unsave" alt="Unsave" >
        <span class="saved"></span>
    </div>
    Unsave
</a>
```

Now onlick of save_unsave function i want to update the html design as below:

```
 <a class=" save" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="save_unsave('save','UID','ID',this);">
        <div class="jopt_iconwrap" title="Save" alt="Save" >
            <span class=""></span>
        </div>
        Save
    </a>
```

I am trying to do this in the function:

**jQuery**

```
if(type == 'save')
    {
            var new_type = "'unsave'";
            jQuery(elem_obj).html("");
            jQuery(elem_obj).html('<a onclick="save_unsave('+new_type+','+uid+','+id+',this);" class="saved" href="javascript:void(0);"><div class="jopt_iconwrap" title="Unsave" alt="Unsave"><span class="saved"></span></div>Unsave</a>');
    }
    else if(type == 'unsave')
    {

        var new_type = "'save'";
        jQuery(elem_obj).html("");
        jQuery(elem_obj).html('<a onclick="save_unsave('+new_type+','+uid+','+id+',this);" class=" save" href="javascript:void(0);"><div class="jopt_iconwrap" title="Unsave" alt="Unsave"><span class="mico"></span></div>Save</a>');

    }
```

How can we do this in jquery.Please help me in the i have the elmenet object in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply i will suggest you to use `replaceWith()` in place of `.html()` it will work properly for you.

Comment: perfect this i was missing it is working as desired thank u

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('a').click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('save')) {
    $(this).removeClass('save').addClass('unsave');
    $(this).text('Unsave')
    $(this).attr('id','save')

  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('unsave').addClass('save');
    $(this).text('Save')
    $(this).attr('id','unsave')

  }



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class=" save">
  <div class="jopt_iconwrap" title="Save" alt="Save">
    <span class=""></span>
  </div>
  Save
</a>
```

Try this way

Comment: i have updated the question how i am trying to do this

Comment: will u please create a fiddle for the same for me pls

Comment: ok what should happened if the text is save?what should happened if unsave sorry i dont understand the question clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `onclick` event, like this:

```
$('.save')[0].onclick = function() {
  save_unsave('save', 'UID', 'ID', this);
}
```